# Performing mergesort with only the array and array size

Tags: c++, sorting, mergesort

```
void mergeSort(int array[], int const begin, int const end)
{
    if (begin >= end)
        return; // Returns recursively
  
    auto mid = begin + (end - begin) / 2;
    mergeSort(array, begin, mid);
    mergeSort(array, mid + 1, end);
    merge(array, begin, mid, end);
}
```

I've been reviewing the code above from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/

whilst trying to come up with a version that only takes the array and the size of the array from the user. I considered a static variable, or one defined outside the scope of the function that is initialized and set to 0, but keep getting an out of bounds error.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please elaborate and add more details for ***keep getting an out of bounds error***.

Comment: What are you really asking about? How the shown code work? How to help you fix your own (unknown) code? Something else? Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Just don't use the int array[] syntax, you will loose all size information on the array (and thus it is too easy to write buggy code).  Either use std::vector or make a function template for mergeSort accepting the array as int (&array)[N] (with N being a std::size_t template parameter).

Comment: You could create an entry function that takes 2 parameters: `mergeSort(int array[], int size)`, which just calls `mergeSort(array, 0, size)`.